# WordPress - displaying posts from a category on the same page

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have a page named "Shop". On that page I display a custom menu, which contains links to categories like "Books", "Shoes" etc. Whenever I click one of those links/categories it takes me to a relevant category page, for example `/category/books/`.

I do not want it to redirect me to a category page, I want it to display posts on the same page ("Shop") that the menu item was clicked on. The only problem I have encountered trying to accomplish this, is the fact that I do not know how to change the custom menu behavior. I don't want it to redirect me, but instead send a GET value to **the same page ("Shop")**. Then the shop page would take that GET value and display relevant posts.

I know how to display posts from a category etc. I just don't know how to change the behavior of the custom menu.

Could anybody help me? I would be grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Original Answer:**

Use `wp_get_nav_menu_items`:

```
$menu_slug = 'YOUR_MENU_SLUG';
$menu_id = get_nav_menu_locations()[$menu_slug];
$menu_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items($menu_id);

foreach($menu_items as $item){
    if($item->object == 'category'){
        print('<p>Title: ' . $item->title . '<br>ID: ' . $item->object_id . '</p>');
    }
}
```

`wp_get_nav_menu_items` returns an array of menu items. You get several information on the item, like type (post, category, ...), id, title and so on.
See http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_nav_menu_items for a full list of properties.

Hope this helps :)

**Update:**

Assuming your permalink setting is set to default, the following code will print a modified menu that uses GET.

```
$menu = wp_nav_menu(array(
    'theme_location'=>'YOUR_MENU_LOCATION',
    'echo'=>0,
));
$new_url = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] . '?shop_page=$1';
$menu = preg_replace('/href="[^"]*cat=(.+)"/', 'href="'.$new_url.'"', $menu);
print($menu);
```

The regex may not be the best as it ignores other GET values and I'm not experienced on them. If your permalink setting is different and every time you change it, you will have to edit the regex.

Comment: So basically I have to create a "custom custom menu"? There is no way to stop that redirecting to category pages?

Comment: Yes there is! Somehow i missed the `echo` argument of `wp_nav_menu`... If you set that to 0, the code will be returned instead of printed. YOu then can use a regex to change the links. I'm working on an example and will edit my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your update. The only problem I see here is the fact that whenever I would add a new category it won't really update the URL automatically. Though still it seems as it is the only way and if there are no answers that solve that problem here I will mark this answer as correct. Anyway, I am voting your answer up, thank you!

Comment: What do you mean, it won't update automatically? Is only the first url changed?

Comment: For example let's say I create 5 categories, then I apply your example to create custom URLs that send data through the GET parameter. After, let's say, two months I add next categories. I would have to modify the code for it to change the URLs of those categories too. Or maybe I didn't understand your code well enough?

Comment: Every time this script is executed (= somebody browses to it), it will get your menu entries as they are in this point in time and change all links that fit the regex, then print the entire menu. It's not important how many links there are. You can try that right now by adding another category to your menu (for test purposes).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59367/discussion-between-paolo-and-pe-ter).

Comment: Okay, now I understand everything, chat is not necessary :). I am choosing your answer as the correct one :).